# How to determine if sql table is Temporal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

With SQL Server 2016 supporting [Temporal Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935015.aspx) I wonder if there is a way to determine if a table is currently temporal? Something like

`select * from sys.objects where object_id('dbo.MyTable', 'u') = parent_object_id and type_desc = "SYSTEM_VERSIONED"`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> ```
> SELECT temporal_type
> FROM   sys.tables
> WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTable', 'u')
> ```
>
> 0 = NON_TEMPORAL_TABLE
>
> 1 = HISTORY_TABLE
>
> 2 = SYSTEM_VERSIONED_TEMPORAL_TABLE

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Another way of listing temporal tables with their history tables together is given in this SQL tutorial as [List Temporal and History Tables in a SQL Server Database](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2016/create-sql-server-2016-temporal-table.aspx)

```
select
 t.object_id,
 t.name,
 t.temporal_type,
 t.temporal_type_desc,
 h.object_id,
 h.name,
 h.temporal_type,
 h.temporal_type_desc
from sys.tables t
inner join sys.tables h on t.history_table_id = h.object_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple answer to the original basic question:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name = 'MyTable'
    AND schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo')
    AND temporal_type_desc = 'SYSTEM_VERSIONED_TEMPORAL_TABLE'
```

And here is a similar query looking for the actual system managed history table:

```
SELECT h.* FROM sys.tables p 
INNER JOIN sys.tables h
    ON p.history_table_id = h.object_id
WHERE p.name = 'MyTable'
    AND p.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo')
    AND p.temporal_type_desc = 'SYSTEM_VERSIONED_TEMPORAL_TABLE';
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the system versioned tables, the associated history tables, the retention policy, and whether the retention policy is enabled at the database level.

[From Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-temporal-tables-retention-policy)

```
SELECT DB.is_temporal_history_retention_enabled,
SCHEMA_NAME(T1.schema_id) AS TemporalTableSchema,
T1.name as TemporalTableName,  SCHEMA_NAME(T2.schema_id) AS HistoryTableSchema,
T2.name as HistoryTableName,T1.history_retention_period,
T1.history_retention_period_unit_desc
FROM sys.tables T1  
OUTER APPLY (select is_temporal_history_retention_enabled from sys.databases
where name = DB_NAME()) AS DB
LEFT JOIN sys.tables T2   
ON T1.history_table_id = T2.object_id WHERE T1.temporal_type = 2
```

Comment: Seems the history_retention_policy only came in SQL 2017. E.g. the above query doesn't work in SQL 2016 unless the retention bits are removed. I hope I'm wrong though, and there's something I'm doing wrong here in SQL 2016???